# URLClassLoader - Using an encrypted Jar

Tags: java, class, memory, loader, encryption

I have seen many Encrypted Class Loaders. Such as:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html?page=2

That one specifically is the one I am trying to adapt to my needs.

I have basically have an encrypted JAR that I have decrypted into a byte array ("byte[] decrypt;").
I now want to use that byte array to load the classes so I do not need to create a file on the hard drive containing the decrypted jar.

I am needing it to use URLClassLoader and NOT ClassLoader as I have another array ("URL[] urls") that the ClassLoader needs to take from. (Unless you can do this with a normal Class Loader?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty similar to this SO post:

[Load a Byte Array into a Memory Class Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832421/load-a-byte-array-into-a-memory-class-loader)

I think the only modification here is to take advantage of a parent classloader - so when you create an instance of your custom class loader, pass in a URLClassLoader to the constructor

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
  public MyClassLoader(URLClassLoader parent, byte[] decryptedBytes) {
    super(parent);
    this.decryptedBytes = decryptedBytes;
  }

  protected byte[] decryptedBytes;

  public Class findClass(String name) {
    byte[] b = loadClassData(name);
    if (b != null) {
      return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    } else {
      // delegate to parent URL classloader
      getParent().findClass(name);
    }
  }

  private byte[] loadClassData(String name) {
    // load the class data from the connection
    // use JarInputStream, find class, load bytes ...
    . . .
  }
}
```

Comment: It's similar but not quite the same! :P The old one worked pretty much perfectly for what I needed doing. This time I need to get it to load into memory. Also, this one worked a treat - kinda'! Thanks Chris. - One problem is the getParent().findClass method, it can't seem to find the UrlClassLoader and instead is using ClassLoader. (Unless I can just make my own getParent() method?)

Comment: getParent will return the URLClassLoader (which extends ClassLoader), so if need be you can cast - but i don't see why you would need to, the findClass method delegates to the URLClassLoader if the loadClassData method returns null (i.e. it can'd find the class in the decrypted byte array).

Comment: Interesting, I ended up just casting it which worked fine. All is working perfectly now, thanks for all the help! Much appreciated.